# JQuery Select Form Array Name

Tags: jquery, ajax, arrays, forms

I have a form that looks like the following:

```
<input type="text" name="item[101][0][date]" value="2012" />
<input type="text" name="item[101][0][price]" value="10.00" />
<input type="text" name="item[101][0][colour]" value="orange" />
<input type="text" name="item[101][1][date]" value="2013" />
<input type="text" name="item[101][1][price]" value="5.00" />
<input type="text" name="item[101][1][colour]" value="blue" />
```

And I would like to be able to select the entire array from the first 2 keys and store the whole lot as an array in javascript so I can send it via AJAX to PHP.

I've got this in jQuery at the moment, but it doesn't seem to produce what I'm after.

```
var products = $('input[name~="item['+itemCode+']['+basketId+']"]');
```

Where itemCode and basketId and retrieved from a submit button (which is working).

Once I have this array called "products" I know how to serialise it and send it as a post request, I just don't seem to be able to end up with an array such as:

```
products[101][0][date] = 2012
products[101][0][price] = 10.00
products[101][0][colour] = orange
```

Or:

```
products[101][1][date] = 2013
products[101][1][price] = 5.00
products[101][1][colour] = blue
```

Any help with this would be appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest using data-* HTML5 attributes to store data at different holders instead of everything stored in the name. Something like:

```
<input type="text" data-category="101" data-index="0" data-id="date" value="2012" />
```

Selection then would be performed the following way:

```
var input = $('input[data-category=' + category + '][data-index=' + index + '][data-id=' + id + ']');
```

This also allows you to select all items of the same category easily, or with the same index, etc.

The array would be constructed like:

```
var products = [];
// Define category, index and id
products[category][index][id] = $('input[data-category=' + category + '][data-index=' + index + '][data-id=' + id + ']').val();
```

Comment: If I use this method, can you give me an example of how I'd select all the inputs based on their data-itemcode and data-basketId in JQuery then?

Comment: I updated the example with how you would select based on the data attributes.

Comment: Ok. Once I have "input" (or "products" as I've called it). How do I end up with an array as per the last section of my question above? If I attempt an "alert(products[date]);" or "alert(products[101][0][date]);" I don't get any output!

Comment: I see you've added the part about the products array. I would like iterate through all instances of itemCode and basketId, without me knowing what the 3rd index is. Is there anyway of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

You are using the [attribute contains ***word*** selector (`name~=value`)](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-word-selector/), which does a slightly different thing from what you want:

> This selector matches the test string against each word in the
>   attribute value, where a "word" is defined as a string delimited by
>   whitespace. The selector matches if the test string is **exactly equal
>   to any of the words**.

Use the [attribute starts with selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) (`name^=value`):

```
var products = $('input[name^="item['+itemCode+']['+basketId+']"]');
```

Either use the [attribute contains selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/) (`name*=value`):

```
var products = $('input[name*="item['+itemCode+']['+basketId+']"]');
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/RCTS2/)**.

Comment: That doesn't seem to work at all as per my question (tried with ^ and ~). When I try "alert(products[101][0][date]);" I get nothing at all!

Comment: @AndyBarlow: You need to take the `.val()` of each element.

Comment: Can you give me an example? I really want to end up with just a plain boring javascript array of products selected by their keys.

Comment: @AndyBarlow: Can't you modify your HTML to use `data-*` attributes for example? It's not easy and it's very error prone to store a multi-dimensional array in an attribute. I'll put an example, but please consider changing your HTML structure.

Comment: I can probably change my HTML if I absolutely must. If you could change your demo fiddle to include the method I was intending to use I'd be hugely appreciative.

Comment: @AndyBarlow: Take a look at this demo http://jsfiddle.net/QPTyr/1, and see if it does what you need, the required array is called `items`.